# How to use DateTimeField in Django with SQLite database correctly?

Tags: django, sqlite, datetime

I have problem with use of `DateTimeField` in Django. In model I have field

```
startTime = models.DateTimeField()
```

And I created correspondin column in SQLite database table

```
startTime datetime NOT NULL
```

And it does not work, I have `AttributeError`. I know SQLite does not support datetime type. It can storage datetime as text, real or integer. There are special sqlite function for working with date and time. 
The problem is that I don't know how to join all together. I want to use default django widget for datetime, that's why I declare in model `models.DateTimeField()`. But it can not storage in database. If I use `models.IntegerField()`, it will be storage in database, but I will not have datetime widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found error in my database. I created column `startTime` not by `manage.py syncdb`, but from command line. And I storages in it not correct data at that moment. I removed these data from table and problem is solved.